# Python csv.reader: is cell string or number?

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python csv.reader() problem:
I have a textfile, containing data that can basicly been read by csv.reader but I need one extra feature, that I am afraid is not included yet:
instead of returning the value of the cell, I need it to return a pair (a,b) where the a is the cell content and b is True or False depending on if the reader did remove quotes from the cell.

Example: my file contains a line (not visible here: the cells are tabs delimited):

`"123"  123 """123"""`

it should return for it `[(123,True), (123, False), ("123",True)]`

I can't use quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE because I have quotes and newlines in the cells.

Any Idea on how I do "overload" the reader funktion? Or is there anything else I can use?

Comment: Unfortunately, the csv module (at least in standard Python) is not a pure Python module but calls C code. You will have to roll your own, but as csv has many corner case, my advise is to get a source Python distrib and read how it is implemented. You could then make a specific module *based on standard csv* either in C + Python or plain Python. Alternatively, if you only need a subset of the full CSV specification, a custom dedicated module/function is probably the way to go

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to include the code you have so far. Could you give a link to a sample CSV file ? (using pastebin for example)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `input.csv` contains (containing tabs):

```
"123"   123 """123"""
```

You could just parse it without the CSV library as follows:

```
def remove_quotes(cell):
    no_quotes = cell.strip('"')
    length_diff = len(cell) - len(no_quotes)

    if length_diff == 0:
        try:
            return (int(cell), False)
        except ValueError:
            return (cell, False)
    elif length_diff == 2:
        try:
            return (int(no_quotes), True)
        except ValueError:
            return (cell, True)
    else:
        return (no_quotes, True)
```

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        line = [remove_quotes(cell) for cell in line.strip().split('\t')]
        print(line)

This would print:

```
[(123, True), (123, False), ('123', True)]
```

The `remove_quotes()` function removes any quotes and detects any length changes and creates the required tuple accordingly.